# How can I prove this result in combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics

A collection of $M=n_1+n_2+⋯+n_k$ distinct objects can be allocated to $k$ locations so that location $i$ receives exactly $n_i$ objects $(i=1,2,\ldots,k)$ in $C(M;n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)=\frac{M!}{n_1!\,n_2!\,\ldots,n_k!}$ ways.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What is `C`? And, most importantly, is this a *Mathematica* question?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How can I prove this combinatorics problem?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154849/how-can-i-prove-this-combinatorics-problem) (due to migration)